# using mysql NOW() function to update row in database not working in PHP query

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I am trying to use the NOW() mysql function to update the datetime column for an inserted row. The datetime column is called 'transaction'. I tried finding a similar PHP function to mirror/mimic the datetime format but couldn't find one suitable.

```
 $purchase = query("INSERT INTO `Portfolio`(`id`, `symbol`, `shares`, `transaction`, `transType`) VALUES ((?),(?),(?),(?),(?)) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shares = shares + VALUES(shares)",$user,$symbol,$shs,NOW(),"BUY");
```

Comment: why don't you use `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use PHP `date` function:

```
date("Y-m-d H:i:s")
```

to put current time

or you can not bind the parameter:

```
$purchase = query("INSERT INTO `Portfolio`(`id`, `symbol`, `shares`, transaction`, `transType`) VALUES (?,?,?,NOW(),?) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE shares = shares + VALUES(shares)",$user,$symbol,$shs,"BUY");
```

Comment: would not binding leave vulnerability to SQL injections?

Comment: No, if you use mysql function that doesn't use any parameters this query will be safe. You need to use parameters only for data that potentially are unsafe. Result of `NOW()` mysql function is safe so you don't need to bind this paramter

Answer (score 0):

The NOW() goes in place of one of the "?", not in the bind list.

If you also wanted to update that field in case the statement turns into an UPDATE, then you need it in the SET also.

Answer (score 0):

```
$database = new database;
$now = $database->now();

class database {
...
public function now($query = "SELECT NOW();"){
        $sth = $this->connect->prepare($query);
        // execute
        if ($sth->execute()) {
            $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            return $result["NOW()"];
        } else {
            echo "\nPDO::errorInfo():\n";
            print_r($sth->errorInfo());
            echo "\nQuery:\n";
            echo $query;
            echo "\nParam:\n";
        }
    }
}
```